# Python regex, avoid skipping brackets

Tags: python, regex, brackets

I want to replace a regex with '*', but only if the regex is out side of <>. The whole point is to not interfere with the html tags.

I use this to replace:

```
re.sub(r'SOMEREGEX(?=[^>]*(<|$))', '*', line)
```

However I ran into his problem: if my regex is:

```
f.*k
```

Then this:

```
fzzzzzzzzz<HTMLTAG>zzzzzzzk
```

Would become an '*', which I don't want. How do I overcome this problem?

Constraints:

-All brackets are matched

-No nested brackets

-SOMEREGEX is provided by the user. I prefer not changing that.

Comment: [You can't parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/350351)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try replacing the `.` character - "any character at all" - with the character class `[^<>]`, which matches any character **except** the angle brackets, `<>`. This would give the regex `f[^<>]*k`. This would match `facebook` but not `face<b>book`.

There are still things that can go wrong with this, though. Have you considered using a proper HTML parser instead of regular expressions? BeautifulSoup is easy, tasty and fun.

Comment: The thing is, I don't have any control over the given regex. I just want to protect all my tags, and they can be anywhere in the middle of the sentence

Comment: Can you please clarify your constraints? (Edit your question to include any additional information that's relevant.)

Answer (score 0):

Search between the end and start angle brackets:

```
re.sub(r'(^|>)f[^<]*k(<|$)', r'\1*\2', line)
```

The `\1` and `\2` are required to replace the angle brackets that the pattern may have removed from `line`.